# Equivalent of sessions on windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I am working with c# windows 8.1, I want to use sessions on my application (keeping trace of the user's information) how can I do it on windows 8?
Does anyone can help please?
Thank you

Comment: Under what context ? Web applications ? winforms ? metro app ? And since you talk about "equivalent", then what do you compare windows 8.1 to ?

Comment: metro app context, I am comparing with asp.net

Comment: you should use local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the user's information in `Local Database` to keep track of user.

You can find [**here**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/A-Simple-Windows-Store-85f29843) **A Simple Windows Store Application Using a Local Database**

Hope this helps :)